# How to configure ConverseJS to turn on chat states (XEP 0085)?

Tags: converse.js

ConverseJS mentions that is supports chat states ("Mark is typing..." notifications), but I couldn't find any documentation that would explain how to actually turn it on.

I use [ConverseJS 1.0.3](https://github.com/jcbrand/converse.js/tree/v1.0.3) and Readme mentions it supports "Typing and state notifications XEP 85"

Any ideas?

Comment: It's turned on and active by default.

Comment: Hi JC, thanks for the reply. For some reason it doesn't work for me... Is there maybe something on the eJabberd server that has to be configured?

Comment: I don't think so. You're using quite an old version of converse.js, I'd suggest trying out the latest version.